# Security Rules for Cloud Firestore - User access only their own docs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a `users` collection and the following rule obviously works:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

The following two snippets don't allow access though and I can't figure out why:

```js
// Fails:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if database == "users"
    }
  }
}

//Fails:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /{collectionName}/{documentId} {
    allow read, write : if collectionName == "users";
  }
}
```

I'm looking at [this](https://khreniak.medium.com/cloud-firestore-security-rules-basics-fac6b6bea18e) and want something like this:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /users/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
}
```

But this also fails.  I'm clearly missing the point.  How can I allow only the user to access their document?

### ***EDIT***

Here's my front end code in my Vuex Store:

```js
async getUserData ({ commit }) {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'users'))
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(`${doc.id} => ${JSON.stringify(doc.data())}`)
  })
},
```

As I mentioned this will print (**all**) users right now.  For example, something like this for each user:

```js
Z9FiUutcAIVnXXXXXXXX => {“machineIds”:{“latest":"a","a":"M6021C67FA","b":"M6021C67FA"},"email":"dave@domain.co.uk","unlock”:”XXX”}
```

Now, I need to only access the logged in user, as mentioned.

So I played around a little and this 'works' (actually prints all records):

```js
// Works:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collectionName}/{documentId} {
      allow read, write : if collectionName == "users";
    }
  }
}
```

But these don't and give `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`:

```js
// Fails:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}

// Fails:

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{email} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.email == email;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the second and expected it to work because my data structure is like so and doesn't have a `userId`.

Here is my data structure:

[image: structure]

I also played around a little with the `Rules Playground` to no avail.

I feel incredibly embarrassed to ask about this as I know I'm doing something wrong and the solution is super simple.  Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Security rules only make sense when paired with app code that performs a query.  Please edit the question to show your query so we can see how it would be affected by the rules.

Comment: I'll point out that the rules should [always start](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#service_and_database_declaration) a match with `match /databases/{database}/documents`.  That should never be removed.  Only modify the matches for the collections and documents nested under that.  This is what you'll see throughout the documentation.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. Away from my machine for a few hours but I’ll update the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Question updated and both your comments here make sense - upvoted.

Comment: Firestore currently supports only 1 database per project with the name `(default)` so the `allow read, write: if database == "users"` rule will always result to `false` and deny the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters). Security rules do not change the result of a query -- they simply allow or deny a query based on the criteria you define.  The client code is requesting all of the documents under `users`, and the result of that query will either be everything or an error saying that they are not allowed to have everything.

If a user should only be able to get their own documents, you will need to add a filter into the query that requests only those documents, and check that the filter is correct in the rules.  Typically people [use the Firebase Auth UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_authuid) as the value to store in a document or its ID to determine if it should be usable that by that user.

Also you should know that `match` expressions only look at the path of the document with collection and document names.  They don't match fields of documents like you're trying to do with email.  If you want a user to only be able to get documents where their Firebase Auth email address is a certain value, then your rule should look like this:

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{id} {
      allow read: if request.auth.email == resource.data.email;
    }
  }
```

You will want to take some time to learn about what `resource` does in your queries.  The [documentation for "Secure and query documents based on a field"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_a_field) will help.

With that rule, now your client app's query needs a filter on the `email` with the exact value of their auth email string (which is only guaranteed to be present when using email/password auth).